# Vuejs history mode - Acces direct category page returns 404 (apache)

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I created a mini test here with multiple pages: http://media.eurolines-group.ro/website/
When I work on localhost and acces one of the pages, it works very fine - but when I try to acces it on the server (apache) I get a 404 error - ex: http://media.eurolines-group.ro/website/about.
Is there a way that when I enter directly on /about , /contact / jobs - to return the page?

Here are my scripts:

**htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Router/index.js**

```
export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: '/website/',
  routes: [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        component: Home
    },
    {
        path: '/about',
        name: 'About',
        component: About
    },
    {
        path: '/contact',
        name: 'Contact',
        component: Contact
    },
    {
        path: '/jobs',
        name: 'Jobs',
        component: Jobs
    }
  ]
})
```

**config.js**

```
build: {
    // Template for index.html
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'),

    // Paths
    assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: 'http://media.eurolines-group.ro/website',
```

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out with someone help - If someone else encounter this problem: I replace all in my htaccess with this:

```
FallbackResource index.html
```